# override mybatis-spring-boot-starter xml files

Tags: overriding, mybatis

I'm trying to override the XML file again. I have two mapper files with the same namespace
, one is in a jar package, and I'm going to override it. I'm using 1.3.2 Version of mybatis-spring-boot-starter.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's far too little information for anyone to possibly help.  Posting a code attempt would be a good start.

Comment: I can think if no reliable way to accomplish this. You should just use a different namespace for your new mapper.

Comment: @JeffButler 

i see,but i have so many xml files in the same prefix namespace,just like this.

this is example springboot project
https://github.com/louandme/mybatis-spring-boot-starter-override-test.git

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.